# EF Core 7 Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

I have .net 7 web api and EF Core 7.0.11 and I'am trying to get operator object from DB by
login column (nvarchar(100), nullable).

```
List<Operator> op = await _dbContext.Operator.Where(w => w.Login == "somelogin").ToListAsync();
```

But in result I have error:

```
An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'DataBase.DBContext.DbContext'.
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
```

When i try get operator by id works.
List t = await _dbContext.Operator.Where(w => w.IdOperator == 1).ToListAsync();

I have one more project that was updated from .net 6 to .net 7 and the same method of getting the operator via his login works. Did I forget something?

//edit

The problem is with enable in *.csproj
When nullable is `enable` all properties in dbcontext class should have `?` in type when column was nullable.

Comment: Are you sure your migrations are up to date? Feels like a mismatch between your code and the database. Run migraine and try creating one to see if it comes up empty

Comment: Mark nullable members using reference nullability operator `?`, like `property string? Login { get; set;}`. Check other properties also.

Comment: Problem is in "<Nullable>enable</Nullable>"  in *.csproj. Works when disabled but why?

Comment: EF Core 7 optimised this part, they stopped check for NULLs returned by ADO.NET provider if member is not nullable. It makes some performance improvements during mapping big recordsets.  Enabling `Nullable` instructs compiler to inject special attributes for members, which are detected by EF Core.